# Umbraco Multiple Member Picker I want to hide All Member

Tags: umbraco7

I'm using Multinode Tree Picker to create multi member picker. Because I have only 1 member type so I want to hide All Members section in overlays. Are there any solutions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can specify the allowed member type in "`Allowed items of type`" field on Datatype configuration.
[Add allowed member types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkYJh.png)